# Read csv and split single column to multiple

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm new to Python. I use python to read a csv file. The data appears to be like multiple columns, but when I try to manipulate the data, it is actually one single column. How can I separate them into multiple columns as dataframe?
I used

```
df = pd.read_csv('disease_data.csv', engine='python', sep=',')
```

to read it.

[image]

[image]

The data is like this, a sequence of integers:

```
25577, 7, 14, 5, 7, 8
25581, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6
25585, 0, 8, 9, 3, 5
25591, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5
```

Comment: Please show the code you use to read the data.

Comment: And also post a sample of the `csv` as formatted text, and not as an image,  so we can actually use it...

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: Use: `df = pandas.read_csv(‘/path/to/file.csv’)`

Comment: I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this will help you but this is How I read a CSV File that was for a School Project

```py
with open('members.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            # Index 0 - Forename, Index 1 - Surname, Index 2 - Category, Index 3 -Password 
            forenames.append(row[0])
            surnames.append(row[1])
            categories.append(row[2])
            passwords.append(row[3])
```

This used the module CSV `import csv`

Here is the CSV

```
Angela,Rich,Adult,Twinkle$
Siraj,Adkins,Junior,Password123%
Stefano,Love,Senior,Qwerty#
Cameron,Wilder,Junior,Wildtime$
Griff,Sutherland,Adult,Geordieman2%
Amaan,Sosa,Senior,Mollymoo5#
Isaak,Schroeder,Junior,Christmas#
Nana,Galloway,Junior,TheGrinch$
Lila,Blanchard,Adult,Tigger27$
Eren,Acosta,Adult,Jamjar1992#
```

Comment: Please try to only answer well-asked questions. As it stands right now, it is not clear what is the exact input, what is the problem/error etc. While your answer might be helpful, it is not clear how it is related to the question...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the [pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) docs.

Use example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to convert that single column from a df object to a pd.Series object - using `series_name = df1.iloc[0]` where 0 is the header for the only column we have. Be back with more.